# How to develop an Android App which will accept user social media logins and also store the data user has entered on cloud. How to go about it?

Tags: android, json, authentication, cloud

I am new to Android but am learning new things everyday. I am currently working on a game which would require users to login and then enter some data. This data would be available to other users of the app to modify/edit/save. Also I want to make a version of the App on Google Glass as well. SO the Glass App needs to have access to this data.

Could you please point me in the possible direction for creating the cloud infrastructure of the app? I have heard something about JSON. Will that be useful this case? Where can I find cheap servers which will store the user data?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the user data I highly suggest to use https://parse.com/ . They provide api and we can easily store data. That is one of the easiest way to store the user data.